# Boost regex match with reading from file

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have following code in C++ that is supposed to read a file line by line and match a regex to get the information that I am seeking. The regex is valid as given by [this link](http://regex101.com/r/vX2wN5/1) , though the program isn't finding it. Here's the program:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
int main() 
{ 
    boost::regex expr1("Property\(C\):\sIP\s\=(.*)\n");
    boost::smatch what1;
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream myfile("document.txt");
    if(myfile.is_open()){
        std::cout <<"FILE OPEN " <<std::endl;
        while(getline(myfile, line))
        {
            std::cout <<" LINE : " << line <<std::endl;
            if (boost::regex_search(line, what1, expr1)) 
            { 
                std::cout<<"MATCH FOUND " <<std::endl;
            for(int i(0); i<what1.size(); i++)
                std::cout << "WHAT " <<i<<" "<<what1[i] <<std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The file is supposed to contain following datas:

```
Property(C): IP = 127.0.0.1
Property(C): PORT = 9999
Property(C): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\Users\logpoint\Downloads\Compressed\command_lines_and_setups_source\Setup\Debug
Property(C): CLIENTUILEVEL = 0
Property(C): CLIENTPROCESSID = 28184
Property(C): VersionDatabase = 200
```

Is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: No need to escape the `=`, it's not a special character. You need to use double backslashes instead of simple backslash.

Comment: Should I be adding double backslash for space character too

Comment: Yes adding two backslash worked thanks.

Comment: yes, for all shorthand character classes: `Property\\(C\\):\\sIP\\s=(.*)\\n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by  Casimir et Hippolyte, Adding two backslashes in my regex worked. i.e. my regex was :

```
"Property\\(C\\):\\sIP\\s=(.*)"
```